# Put a vertical line to separate 2 subgraphs

Tags: floats

I have one figure which contains 2 figures:

```
\begin{figure*}
  \begin{center}
    \subfigure[A]{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      ....
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \quad
    \subfigure[B]{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      ....
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  \end{center}
\end{figure*}
```

Could anyone tell me how to add a vertical line between them to visually separate them?

Comment: A tabular with {c|c} maybe?

Comment: Can I still keep `subfigure` inside `tabular`?

Comment: @SoftTimur Yes, you can. Note that the `subfigure` package is obsolete and either `subfig` or `subcaption` should be used; the former has a syntax like `subfigure` (but you should use `\subfloat` instead of `\subfigure`). There are *many* spurious spaces in your code.

Comment: Regarding the spurious spaces, do you mean I should add `%` after `{`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following the advice of percusse and egreg:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);   
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{A red square}
            \label{fig:red_square}
        \end{subfigure}
        &
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);      
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{A blue square}
            \label{fig:blue_square}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Two squares}
    \label{fig:two_squares}
\end{figure}            
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you... But if you put `\begin{subfigure}[A longer Text]{0.45\textwidth}`, it seems that the labels under the figures are not well placed...

Comment: The optional argument of the `subfigure` environment does not correspond to its caption, but to a placement specifier; see the table summarising those options on http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures. If you want to add a caption to each `subfigure`, and possibly to the `figure` that contains them, simply use `\caption` as in my code, which I just updated.